# QGIS distance in meter instead of decimal degrees

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance, buffer, centroids

I use a shapefile of the US counties and I want to create buffer zones around the centroid of each county. However, the distance is measured in decimal degrees. As far as I understood, I have to change the Layer CRS. My problem is that I don't find a matching layer. Is there a layer that I can use for the whole USA? I tried it with WGS84 Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG: 6871) but if I apply this layer, I cannot find my map of the counties anymore.

---

Has anybody already created such buffer zones? It should not be that complicated but it doesn't work

Comment: Actually, you *never* want distance as measured by Web Mercator (which cannot produce accurate distances), and you *don't* want to change the source CRS (which corrupts the source file). Instead you want to change the map canvas CRS, probably to USGS CONUS Alber's equal area.

Comment: I understand that it is better to not change the source CRS. I just checked the CRS of the layer (under "properties" of the layer) and it is written that the assigned CRS is an invalid projection. What does this mean?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438809/88814

Comment: Reproject your data (don't set the projection) to US National Atlas, a search will find the code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Virtual Field** in your table: (1) create a line, (2) transform it to UTM zone and (3) take the line's length

[image: Create a virtual field for the table]

Throw in the formula

[image: Enter distance formula]

Take this for copy pasta:

```
length(
    transform(
        make_line($geometry, make_point(13.26816, 52.31255)),
    'EPSG:4326',
    'EPSG:32632')
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your advice! While searching for the code, I found this website and it really helped:

http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/3/working_with_projections.html

(1. project -> properties -> CRS -> select initial CRS)
2. select features -> select all counties (I used freehand and draw a rectangle including all counties)
3. processing -> toolbox -> vector general -> reproject layer -> choose desired CRS
4. only select new reprojected layer on the right side
5. project -> properties -> CRS -> select new/desired CRS