# Creating correct buffers

Tags: qgis, buffer, united-states

I'd like to create buffers that have a radius of 100 km around the centroids of US counties. First I have the problem that my shapefile uses a layer CRS in decimal degrees. Furthermore, if I create a buffer with degrees, there is the problem, that the distance of the centroid to the edge of the buffer is not the same around the circle. How can I do this?

Comment: Please do not repost Questions [QGIS distance in meter instead of decimal degrees](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439553/qgis-distance-in-meter-instead-of-decimal-degrees)

Comment: No, it does not. I don't understand what I have to do. Sorry if I bother you but I am new to this kind of software and files and I think that it should not be that complicated since the US is often used in research.

Comment: Our purpose here is to compile a list of answered questions, not to answer questions that have been asked repeatedly. If you re-ask the question you just clutter the site with noise. This question has been answered scores of times, for each of the GIS packages. The issue you seem to be tripping over is very common: There's a difference between changing the projection of data (corrupting it) and changing the map canvas draw rules or reprojecting the data to be in planar units (creating a new dataset). The details vary by software package, but the concept is the same.

Comment: THis should answer your question. n your case, I would stick to option 2, geodesic buffers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438809/88814

Answer (score 0):

1. Reproject your centroid shape file to a Cartesian coordinate system, e.g. using the advice from [Which projection is best for mapping the contiguous United States?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141580/which-projection-is-best-for-mapping-the-contiguous-united-states)
2. Set your QGIS project to the same coordinate system
3. Apply the buffer in map units