# How to add circle around points?

Tags: qgis, visualisation

For a point, how do you create circles that shows a certain distance from a point. For instance, I have the following point:

[image]

What I want to have is this:

[image]

For instance, while the black circle represents all the points that are 2 kilometers away from the point, dark red circle represents all the points that are 4 kilometers away.

And is it possible to fill these circles with colors in a non-opaque way while making the map clearly visible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, you need to search for buffer...

Comment: Check this one: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html?highlight=buffers

Comment: Be aware that just applying buffers (as adviced here and also in the posted solution) does not give you real world distances! It very much depends on the CRS you use. If you use Web Mercator (`EPSG:3857`) as seems the case in your screenshot, the buffer distance is no meaningful realworld distance. See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438809/88814

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the layer styling panel (F7)
2. Click the plus sign to add another Symbol layer
3. Change type to Geometry generator, with type Polygon, formula `buffer($geometry,2000)`
4. Set the symbology of the layer

Add another layer with buffer 4000

[image]

Comment: Or to get the circle as new layer use one of the processing tool (Geometry by expression or Buffer)

Comment: See above, comment about buffer distance and CRS!