# Buffer is not yielding the appropriate size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, qgis-3, buffer

I am trying to create a buffer of 10 kilometers around each dot already uploaded. The problem is that these buffers seem to be unreasobly larger than 10km. (Portugal). I have tried to use multiple multiple CRS but it doesn't work. Some people suggested to save layers as .shp but I can't see how to do that (maybe there was an update?). I have been using EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. I have tried some others and couldn't solve the issue.

I have read multiple suggestions in other Questions but couldn't solve so far.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to provide details on exactly *how* you are attempting this task, and provide a screenshot or the resulting geometry (and report your measurement thereof).  Do NOT use Web Mercator to make any distance calculations, for it is ALWAYS wrong in distance.

Comment: Always try put some example of data, like a printscreen or a code to simplify your question

Comment: See this answer how to create correct buffer size, regardless of CRS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438809/88814

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any tool that uses distances must use a projected and non-geographic reference system.
Reproject the geometry to the proper EPSG which should work correctly

Comment: For example [EPSG:27429](https://epsg.io/27429-1945)

Comment: Yes BERA, As I didn't know which system, I preferred not to suggest so as not to confuse

Comment: And certainly not EPSG:3857

Comment: I have now changed the project CRS to ESPG:27429. I changed the World Map and the layer as well. When I create the buffer the same thing happens... When you say "reproject" is there anything I should be particularly careful with?

Comment: Thanks @BERA, I have now been able to sort it!