# How to get correct area in QGIS in local coordinate system?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, area

I vectorized a small area (75,000 square meters in reality) in QGIS in the local coordinate system.
`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=38.48333333333 +k=1 +x_0=1250000 +y_0=-5712900.566 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.57,-140.95,-79.8,0,0.35,0.79,-0.22 +units=m +no_defs` Also i tried UTM N37, but the result is still not close to real.
With different methods of obtaining the area, QGIS shows that the area is about 200,000 square meters. What am I doing wrong and how to get a result close to the real volume?

Comment: Please edit your question to include details of the data and project CRS settings.

Comment: Check your project settings: Project properties -> General -> Measurements -> Elliposoid (for distance and area calculation). Try set this parameter to "None/Planimetric"

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: I'm not trying to start a discussion, I asked a specific question and I want to get a specific answer. For example, how RainForest responded

Comment: See here, solution 3: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438809/88814

Comment: Yes, thanks. This solved my problem)