# How to select lines within a distance of a certain point?

Tags: qgis, distance, select

I am currently dealing with the following issue:

I have a dataset with of the roads of a certain place in The Netherlands. Within this place I added two points.

[image]

I would like to know all the roads which lay in the distance of 350 meter of these points.

1. It is possible to create a buffer around these points, but that will select a bunch of unnecessary lines (lines which are in a buffer of 350 meter of the point, but not reachable in 350 meter by following these roads). For instance see screenshot below: it is not possible to reach the roads in the northeast of the 350 meter buffer by using the roads.

[image]

2. Currently I am using the OSM tool, which create a more precise bufferpolygon. But still it is not that precise, because little account is taken of water, parks, etc, things which are not crossable by using the roads.

I would like the following:

Select all roads that are within 350 meters of the point by only using the roads.

Comment: Hi Marius, welcome to GIS SE. Your question is unclear to me. You want to select streets? Why do you have water(?) then? What unnecessary lines are selected? How should we know what you want to select and what not, based on what criteria. Once you say you want to select lines, afterwards you mention selecting polygons... Like this, it's difficult to understand the problem. Please revised your question by editing it.

Comment: By the way: see here for the challenge of selecting correct buffer distances, based on CRS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438809/88814

Comment: Are you asking how to select everything within 350 m walking distance?

Comment: I think you want an Isochrone (or equal time) zone - for that you will need a routing engine and a network. See if any of https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=isochrone answer your question or help you refine it