# Trouble with Buffers using EPSG:5070 QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I've been trying to create a buffer layer around point sources in QGIS. I'm using the EPSG:5070 co-ordinate system, everything I input is in this system, including the base project. I've tried multiple different co-ordinate systems and all are giving buffers that are way too large. EPSG:5070 has units in meters but when I put in the necessary distance, it seems like it's measuring in degrees. The point data has come from a csv file which is in decimal lat long format. They plot fine and in the right place and my vector map and raster are all georeferenced ok, it's just the buffers that are wildly out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How did you change your cars?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between layer CRS and project CRS? See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 Maybe your project is in `EPSG:5070`, but the layer is still in `lat/long` as you loaded them? Then of course buffers will be in degrees. Also please be aware not to change the layer's CRS, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 In any case: try solution 3 from here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438809/88814

Comment: @IanTurton what cars...?

Comment: Sorry, autocorrect I meant CRS

Comment: THanks for your reply, so I've started this over multiple times now and still getting the same result. My project CRS is in ESPG:5070. I then import the files and csv coordinate data and they are all in ESPG:5070, I  saved the files in ESPG:5070 and re-imported them. I just find it confusing why the buffers are coming up so big when everything is in the same CRS and georeferenced, all my point data is in the correct place. The unit is in metres when I go to create the buffer but that is not correctly reflected on the map.